# MS SQL update query with long html string value

Tags: html, sql, html-escape-characters

How can I update the below long html string in a SQL DB table ?

e.g. update WebContentTable set PageHeader = 'the long html below'

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/design/images/favicon.ico" />
<link href="/styles/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/styles/slicknav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/styles/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/styles/fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700,800,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:600,700,800,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.flowtype.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function validateForm(){
alert ('.');
   if ((document.forms[0].search.value=="Search") || (document.forms[0].search.value=="")){
      alert("You must enter a search term");
   } else {
      window.location=''/search?q='' + escape(document.forms[0].search.value);
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your query should work, assuming the column is long enough to hold that HTML content?  What is the actual problem?

Comment: Hi Tim, special characters. e.g. single quotes, double quotes, slash, brackets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting a string literal into SQL Server (and generally, any flavor of SQL), the only thing you should have to escape are the markers for the beginning and end of the string, which in this case are single quotes.

In SQL Server, we can escape a single quote inside a string literal by just doubling it up.  So if you replace `'` with `''` in your HTML string, and then do the update, it should work:

```
UPDATE WebContentTable
SET PageHeader = '<your replaced content here>';
```

You may use any tool to do this replacement, including SSMS.  Just highlight the HTML content and do the replacement.

Actually, maybe you want to do an insert here, or at least add a `WHERE` clause to the update.  In any case, just escape the single quotes and it should work.